# Strange behavior of Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I make adaptive site and on the small screen on the right appears empty space. I do not know where it comes from and how to remove it?
The latest version of Twitter Bootstrap

[image: First screen]

[image: Seconf screen]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your code. This is impossible to diagnose without it.

Comment: **Евгений Маслов** Hi there. Try this first. Comment out using `<!--  -->` to hide your **Navbar**. Do this to check that your navbar is not going wider than the screen width. This will help to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can pretty much guarantee this issue is directly related to improper Bootstrap markup.

1. Make sure you aren’t encasing a full-width carousel inside of a container.
   Carousels already have the proper container inside the item div.
   Don’t encase a standard Bootstrap menu inside a container unless you are doing a custom menu.
2. In the Bootstrap site example, the container is inside the nav element.

See example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Make sure you are using the proper grid structure.
You always have `container > row > class` and if nesting, `container > row > class > row > class` (or `container-fluid`) because nested classes need to be inside rows. The row offsets the container padding.